# bootstrap-3 tooltip doesn't flash accordingly to the js - if - condition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

This is the code I use for register users into mysql db. And I'm using Twitter Bootstrap tooltips, for obtain the following:

1. initially, when the user hover over the textboxes, the string wrote in the `title` attribute will be displayd.
2. if he will write only 2 letters (fe, for the firstname), and presses the submit button, the form won't be submitted, and the new tooltip message should flash and show: "Please use at least 3 letters!".
3. the same algorithm for every input in form.
4. if the user fills in correctly all the textboxes, then the form will be submitted to `register.php`, which will process the data.

   ```
   <form id="form">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" style="width:48%;float:left;" title="The First Name is mandatory! Please use at least 3 letters!"/>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" style="width:48%;float:right;" title="The Last Name is mandatory! Please use at least 3 letters!"/>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cnp" placeholder="CNP" title="The CNP is mandatory! Please use exact 13 numbers!"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="width:48%;float:left;" title="The Password is mandatory! Please use at least 6 chars!"/>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_again" placeholder="Retype the Password" style="width:48%;float:right;" title="This field must be the same as Password field"/>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" title="The Email is mandatory!"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group text-center">
       <button class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
   </div>
   ```

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#firstname').tooltip();
       $('#lastname').tooltip();
       $('#cnp').tooltip();
       $('#password').tooltip();
       $('#password_again').tooltip();
       $('#email').tooltip();
       $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
           var firstname = $('#firstname').val().trim();
           var lastname = $('#lastname').val().trim();
           var cnp = $('#cnp').val().trim();
           var password = $('#password').val().trim();
           var password_again = $('#pssword_again').val().trim();
           var email = $('#email').val().trim();
           if (firstname != '' && firstname.length > 3 && lastname != '' && lastname > 3 && cnp != '' && cnp.length == 13 && password != '' && password.length >= 6 && password_again == password && email != ''){
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "php/register.php",
                   data: {firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, cnp: cnp, password: password, email: email},
                   success: function(response){
                       $('#content').html(response);
                   }
               });
           } else {
               if (firstname.length < 3) {
                   $('#firstname').tooltip('show',function(){
                       title: "Please use at least 3 letters!"
                   });
               }
           }
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

Problems:

1. When the user doesn't put the expected data (fe, at least 3 letters), the tooltip isn't changing accordingly (fe, Please use at least 3 letters!).
2. When the user does put the expected data, then for an unknown reason, the form isn't submitted!

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: the form isn't submitted due to e.preventDefault(); try to add e.preventDefault only on error, or add return true when data are ok

Answer (score 0):

Add text to tooltip dynamically - with var:

```
var msg = '';
msg = 'Please use at least 3 letters';
```

and clear the message before that;

```
    var msg = '';
    if (firstname.length < 3) {
      msg = Please use at least 3 letters;
      $('#firstname').tooltip('show',function(){
          title: msg
       });
    }
```

remove e.preventDefault(); - put it in the part when error occur, as it prevents the default event, ie: submit.

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#firstname').tooltip();
    $('#lastname').tooltip();
    $('#cnp').tooltip();
    $('#password').tooltip();
    $('#password_again').tooltip();
    $('#email').tooltip();
    var msg = '';
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
        var cnp = $('#cnp').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var password_again = $('#pssword_again').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        if (firstname != '' && firstname.length > 3 && lastname != '' && lastname > 3 && cnp != '' && cnp.length == 13 && password != '' && password.length >= 6 && password_again == password && email != ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/register.php",
                data: {firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, cnp: cnp, password: password, email: email},
                success: function(response){
                    $('#content').html(response);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {

            if (firstname.length < 3) {
                msg = 'Please use at least 3 letters!';
                $('#firstname').tooltip('show',function(){
                    title: msg
                });
            }
          e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work: nor the changing tooltip title, nor the submission when the correct details are put.

Comment: try to add 'return true; ' after $('#content').html(response)

Comment: there is wrong adding trim() at the end, I will update with simplified version

Comment: did you find any fix? nothing from what I've tried worked, and I'm feeling like I'm able to find the end of the Universe, than to resolve this problem...

Comment: Have you tried the last code I posted?this is working for me - for submit, there trim() was the issue

Comment: Can you post, please, in www.codepen.io all the code that worked for you. I mean with all inclusions of the resources, cause I guess I'm doing something wrong there. (all html, all js, ...). Thanks!

Comment: `$('#firstname').tooltip('show',function(){` is invalid; `.tooltip()` only accepts 1 argument, not 2. Presumably you want `$('#firstname').tooltip('show');`